# MAUI Bound Entry does not refresh even though the underlying value changes

Tags: refresh, maui

I am really quite confused now, and I am sure that this is something quite simple.

On the "Expense" screen I have this simplified entry:

```
<Entry
    x:Name="entryCountOfReceipts"
    Text="{Binding Expense.CountOfReceipts, Mode=OneWay}"   
    IsReadOnly="true"
    TextChanged="EntryCountOfReceipts_TextChanged">
</Entry>
```

The goal is to show that this expense has N receipts attached.

Why do I have an Entry instead of a label ? Because I want to be able to trigger in the "Expense" page a comparison between the original Expense object and the current one in order to enable or disable the save button.

This comparison is done like this:

In my xaml.cs I have this code:

```
private void EntryCountOfReceipts_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!ScreenIsStillLoading)
    {
        viewModel.ChangesWereMade = Utils.Utils.ChangesWereMade(viewModel.Expense, er_ExpenseOriginal);
    }
}
```

and my Save button has these dataTriggers:

```
<DataTrigger TargetType="Button" Binding="{Binding ChangesWereMade}" Value="false">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="false" />
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Gray" />
</DataTrigger>
<DataTrigger TargetType="Button" Binding="{Binding ChangesWereMade}" Value="true">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Black" />
</DataTrigger>
```

Okay. I load the screen with an expense already having in the SQLite database two receipts attached.

My entry correctly shows 2.

In the viewModel the expense is set up correctly:

```
[ObservableProperty]
private Expense expense;
```

My model looks like this (simplified):

```
public class Expense
    {
        public double Amount { get; set; }

        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int? ID { get; set; }        
        
        [Ignore]
        public int CountOfReceipts { get; set; }

        [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
        public List<Receipt> Receipts { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I take a photo of my receipt, and if everything worked properly, I execute this:

```
Expense.Receipts.Add(receipt);
Expense.CountOfReceipts = Expense.Receipts.Count;
```

(Note: I know I could have bound my view directly to Expense.Receipts.Count, but bear with me).

So in Debug I see that the Expense.CountOfReceipts goes from 2 to 3. Correct.

My viewModel.ChangesWereMade gets set to true, and my Save button gets enabled. Great. But my entry does NOT get refreshed, and persists in showing 2 instead of 3.

Why is it not refreshing to the new bound value ?

What am I missing here ?

Thanks a lot.
Alex.

Comment: is `CountOfReceipts` observable?

Comment: CountOfReceipts is a field of the Expense object, which IS observable (see the line [ObservableProperty] private Expense expense;), and the Expense class is shown above. In the expense page I can bind to, say, Amount (which is also a field of the Expense object) with something like Text="{Binding Expense.Amount}". This time I use Text="{Binding Expense.CountOfReceipts}". So.... I see no difference between the Amound field and the CountOfReceipts. Only that I modify CountOfReceipts from the ViewModel, whereas Amount is changed by the user, in the Entry.

Comment: AFAIK making a property observable does not recursively apply to its child properties.  You need to explicitly make it observable if you want the UI to refresh when the VM changes

Comment: I have tried that, Jason. No luck And, besides, if the values don't change, why does my EntryCountOfReceipts_TextChanged() execute ? It does, it really does. It's just that it doesn;t show on the screen !

Answer (score 0):

You could try raise property changed after add new receipt:

```
Expense.Receipts.Add(receipt);
Expense.CountOfReceipts = Expense.Receipts.Count;
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Expense));
```

Note: you could check the text value in EntryCountOfReceipts_TextChanged handler

```
private void EntryCountOfReceipts_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var a = e.OldTextValue;
    var b = e.NewTextValue;  // please confirm if the newtextvalue is the value you want
}
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, Liqun. It works.... kinda. In my "Expense_View.xaml.cs" page I have this code in OnAppearing - I need to translate from an Enum value to an object: if (Enum.TryParse(viewModel.Expense.DocumentType, out DocumentType myType))
                {
                    DocumentType documentType = myType;
                    pickerDocumentType.SelectedItem = documentType;
                } With the above solution, for some reason I get my Expense object with NULL DocumentType and Category (which are both Enums), and so on Refresh both these fields are set to null when reloading this page.

Comment: Could you please share more codes that can reproduce this issue?  what about the DocumentType, Category and pickerDocumentType?